# A simple question on the exterior calculus

Tags: linear-algebra

There exist various, though certainly equivalent, ways of introducing the wedge product. I am trying to grasp one particular method. This approach implies that we first define $\,\wedge\,$ for unit forms,
 $$
 e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_r}\;\equiv\;r!\,\left[\,e^{i_1}\,\otimes\;.\,.\,.\;\otimes\,e^{i_r}\,\right] \quad,\qquad
 $$
 and then employ the simple theorem
 $$
   \left[\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_{k+l}}\,\right]\;=\;
  \left[\;\;
  \left[\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_k}\,\right]\;\otimes\;\left[\,e^{j_{k+1}}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_{k+l}}\,\right]
  \;\;\right]
 $$
 as a means to extend the definition of $\,\wedge\,$ to arbitrary-order skew forms: 
 $$
 \omega^{k+l}\,=\;\omega^k\wedge\omega^l\,\equiv\;\frac{(k+l)!}{k!\,\;l!}\;\left[\,\omega^k\,\otimes\,\omega^l\,\right]\;\;.
 $$
 As ever, $\,\;[\;.\;.\;.\;]\;\,$ denotes alternation.

To ask my questions, I shall now provide the said development in mode detail.

As agreed, we start out with the DEFINITION:
 $$
  e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_r}\;=\;r!\,\;\left[\,e^{i_1}\,\otimes\,\, .\,.\,.\,\,\otimes\,e^{i_r}\,\right]
 \,\;.
 $$
 Equivalently,
 $$
    e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_r}\;=\;\sum_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_r}\delta^{i_1\,.\,.\,.\,i_r}_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_r}\;\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_r}~~.
 $$

Within my notation, $\,\sum_{j_1 ... j_k}\,$ implies summation over $\,$*all*$\,$ values taken by each index $\,j_s\,=\,1\,,\,.\,.\,.\,,\,n\,$, with $\,$*no*$\,$ additional condition (like $\,j_1\,<\,.\,.\,.\,<\,j_k\,$).

Now we recall that a skew form is a form which is equal to its own alternation, and also recall that alternation of a sum equals the sum of alternations of its summands. This renders us:
 $$ \omega^r(x_1\,,\,.\,.\,.\,,\,x_r)\;=\;\left[\;\omega^r(x_1\,,\,.\,.\,.\,,\,x_r)\;\right]
 $$
 $$  =\;\sum_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_k}^n\,\omega^r_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_r}\;\left[\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_k}\,\right]\;\;(x_1\,,\,.\,.\,.\,,\,x_r)
 $$
 $$ 
 =\;\frac{1}{r!}\,\sum_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_k}^n\,\omega^r_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_r}\;
 e^{j_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{j_r}\;\;\;\,(x_1\,,\,.\,.\,.\,,\,x_r)\;\;,
 $$
whence we see that all $\,e^{j_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{j_r}\,$ make a basis.

Our next step is to use the well known THEOREM: 
 $$
 \left[\;\;
  \left[\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_k}\,\right]\;\;\left[\,e^{j_{k+1}}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_{k+l}}\,\right]
  \;\;\right]\;=\;
 \left[\,e^{j_1}\otimes\, .\,.\,.\,\otimes\,e^{j_{k+l}}\,\right]\;\;,
 $$
 which can be rewritten as
  $$
  \left[\;\;\left(\,\;\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle k!}\;\,e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_k} \,\;\right)\,\otimes\,
  \left(\,\;\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle l!}\;\,e^{i_{k+1}}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_{k+l}} \,\right)\;\;\right]\;=\;
  \frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle (k+l)!}\;\;e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_{k+l}}\,\;.
  $$

To extend the wedge-product definition to arbitrary skew forms, we can multiply the above equality by some $\;\omega_{i_1\;.\;.\;.\;i_k}\;\,\omega_{i_{k+1}\;.\;.\;.\;i_{k+l}}\;$ and sum over all indices:
  $$
  \nonumber
  \left[\;\;\left(\,\;\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle k!}\;\,\omega_{i_1\;.\;.\;.\;i_k}\;\,e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_k} \,\;\right)\,\otimes\,
  \left(\,\;\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle l!}\;\,\,\omega_{i_{k+1}\;.\;.\;.\;i_{k+l}}\;e^{i_{k+1}}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_{k+l}} \,\right)\;\;\right]\qquad\qquad\\
  \label{9}
  $$
  $$
  =\;\frac{\textstyle 1}{\textstyle (k+l)!}\;\;\omega_{i_1\;.\;.\;.\;i_k}\;\,\omega_{i_{k+1}\;.\;.\;.\;i_{k+l}}\;\;e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_{k+l}}\;\,.
  \qquad(1)
  $$
 At this point, we introduce $\,\omega^k\,$ and $\,\omega^l\,$ as
 $$
 \omega^k\;=\;\frac{1}{k!}\;\sum_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_k}^n\,\omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_k}\;e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_k}
 $$
 $$
 \omega^l\;=\;\frac{1}{l!}\;\sum_{j_{k+1}\,.\,.\,.\,j_{k+l}}^n\,\omega_{j_{k+1}\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\;e^{i_{k+1}}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_{k+l}}
 $$
 and also introduce $\;\omega^k\wedge\omega^l\;$ as
 $$
 \omega^k\wedge\omega^l\;\equiv\;\frac{1}{(k+l)!}\;\sum_{j_1\,.\,.\,.\,j_{k+l}}^n\,\omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\;e^{i_1}\,\wedge .\,.\,. \wedge\,e^{i_k}\quad.\;\;\quad
 $$
 Be mindful that in the latter expression the matrix $\,\omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\,$ is not yet defined.

If we choose to set
 $$
 \omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\;\equiv\;\omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_k}\;\omega_{j_{k+1}\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\;\;,\qquad (2)
 $$
 then equality (1) becomes
 $$
 \left[\;\omega^k\,\otimes\,\omega^l\;\right]\;=\;
 \omega^k\wedge\omega^l\,\;.\qquad(3)
 $$

If, however, we set 
 $$
 \omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_{k+l}}\;\equiv\;\frac{(k+l)!}{k!\;l!}\;\omega_{j_1\;.\;.\;.\;j_k}\;\omega_{j_{k+1}\;.\;.\;,\;j_{k+l}}\;\;.\qquad(4)
 $$
 then equality (1) will read as
 $$
 \left[\;\omega^k\,\otimes\,\omega^l\;\right]\;=\;
   \frac{k!\;l!}{(k+l)!}\;
 \omega^k\wedge\omega^l\;\,.\qquad (5)
 $$

Now, my questions:

(a) Is my overall logic consistent? Did I not mess up things in equation (1) ?

(b) In the literature, they traditionally choose convention (4 - 5), not (2 - 3).  Why??

At first glance, choice (4) looks artificial --- but I may be missing some big motivation behind it.

Comment: There's an ambiguity in the notation that gets to the heart of the question: Does $\sum_{j_1 \cdots j_k}^n$ denote the sum over all ordered $k$-tuples of indices in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ (or, equivalently, ordered $k$-tuples of distinct indices in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$), or the sum over all ordered $k$-tuples of indices in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ satisfying $j_1 < \cdots < j_k$? (Only one of these choices is actually reasonable here.)

Comment: In any case, Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, $\S$ 12, tidily addresses exactly this issue, and it discusses the advantages of the two conventions for $\wedge$, which it calls the "determinant convention" and the "Alt convention". In particular, this treatment avoids index expressions in $\omega$.

Comment: Dear Travis, many thanks!
In my notation $\sum$ implies summation over all values taken by each index $\,j_s\,=\,1,\,,\,.\,.\,.\,n\,$, with no additional conditions (like $\,j_1\,<\,.\,.\,.\,<\,j_k\,$).

Within this convention, is my line of reasoning correct?